# laravel, displaying data on a dropdown from another table

Tags: laravel

Hello guys I want to have values from a different table but same database and print them on a dropdown, av tried several ways and here but i get this error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::myVehicles() (View: /home/vagrant/www/martin/resources/views/templates/applications.blade.php)

I want to get them from a table containing all vehicles and print all the vehicles so that the user can select one of the vehicles in the database... here is vehicle model

```html
<?php

namespace Martin\Models;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Vehicle extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
  //
 use Notifiable;

 protected $guard="vehicle";

 protected $table="vehicles";

 protected $fillable=[
         'id',
         'vehicle_registration_number',
      'vehicle_type',
     'vehicle_size',
 ];

public function user(){

return  $this->belongsTo('Martin\Models\User');
}

public function myVehicles(){
  
  $vehicles = Martin\Models\Vehicle::all();

  foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {

echo $vehicle->vehicle_registration_number."-".$vehicle->vehicle_type."-".$vehicle->vehicle_size.' seaters <br/>';

  }


}


}
```

and the following is the dropdown i want to display my data in the applications.blade.php so that a user can select one of the vehicles...

```html
            <select  name="vehicle_registration_number" class="form-control">
                                                    {{Auth::guard('vehicle')->myVehicles()}}
                                                  </select>
```

and also I may ask what name do you assign to the select box do you assign it the same name as the original name of the input i.e text area of the original one? kindly reply... if any more clarification is needed am ready... Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use a controller to handle your models, rather than trying to handle a class from the class itself. If so, you need to create static methods.

In whatever controller you are calling that page, you can get all vehicles

```
public function page()
{
    //whatever you are doing here
    ...
    $vehicles =  Martin\Models\Vehicle::get();
    foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
        $vehicle->description = $vehicle->vehicle_registration_number ."-". $vehicle->vehicle_type ."-". $vehicle->vehicle_size .' seaters';
    }

    return view('view_name', compact('vehicles'));
}
```

Then in your view you loop through vehicles in your select

```
<select name="vehicle_registration_number" class="form-control">
     <option>Select Vehicle</option><!--selected by default-->
     @foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
         <option value="{{ $vehicle->vehicle_registration_number }}">
             {{ $vehicle->description }}
         </option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @Eddy for the  reply,,, kindly  clarify for me,,,  I have Vehicle model and Application Model,,, and the vehicles are on Vehicle Model how do I print items from Vehicle Model to Application Model?

Comment: am still working on this... anyone who can offer me some help?

Comment: Models don't print stuff. I think you should learn Laravel properly from a tutorial before attempting to build something. Models hold the data. Controllers do the logic and call models. Views print/display the data.

Comment: I'm very new to Laravel so please bear with me through any mistakes... you advised me to create the above function in the applicationController which have the logic for directing the user to the application.blade.php which have the dropdown for displaying the data,,, but it gives me the error '   Call to undefined method Martin\Http\Controllers\VehicleController::all()'  again am sorry @Eddy for any inconvenience

Comment: Put your code somewhere I can see. Wherever you want. Even teamviewer. I cannot assist you blindly

Comment: password is also necessary. Don't worry, you can change it anytime.

Comment: password - 8a1zy7